# FOSUserBundle (Symfony2). I have some questions

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

1) How can I add new fields in table and in registration action (show new fields on reg page)? For example: I want to add new fields last_name, age.

2) I added new listener for REGISTRATION_COMPLETED

**/src/Acme/UserBundle/EventListener/RegistrationCompletedListener.php:**

```
<?php
namespace Acme\UserBundle\EventListener;

use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

/**
 * Listener
 */
class RegistrationCompletedListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $router;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED => 'onRegistrationCompletedSuccess',
        );
    }

    public function onRegistrationCompletedSuccess(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $url = $this->router->generate('homepage');

        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
    }
}
```

**/src/Acme/UserBundle/Resources/config/services.yml:**

```
services:
    acme_user.registration_completed:
        class: Acme\UserBundle\EventListener\RegistrationCompletedListener
        arguments: [@router]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

Why don't work?

Comment: [`FormEvent`](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/Form/FormEvent.html) has no method `setResponse`

Comment: public function onRegistrationCompletedSuccess()
    {
        echo 1; exit;
    }

Don't work too... :(

Comment: You should create two questions. It will be much easer to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** You should extend Base User class and add there your new fields, like this:

```
namespace Your\CustomBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{    
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="last_name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $lastName;

}
```

And update `appconfig/config.yml`:

```
#FOSLUserBundle Configuration
fos_user:
    user_class: Your\CustomBundle\Entity
```

Then you need extend and configure new registration form. Here is a [link](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md) how you can do that.

**[Edit]:**

**2)**

Create event listener like this:

```
namespace Your\Bundle\EventListener;

use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent;

class UserListener
{

    public function onRegistrationCompleted(FilterUserResponseEvent $event){

        $user = $event->getUser();
        //do sth....

    }
}
```

And register service for that:

```
services:
    some_name.security.registration_listener:
        class: Your\Bundle\EventListener\UserListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: fos_user.registration.completed, method: onRegistrationCompleted }
```

Comment: What about table? I should change table and add there new fields?

Comment: Yes you should run `php app/console doctrine:schema:update` command to update databese

Comment: I updated my post with answer to your second question.